# checkout page is not working after implementing custom theme

Tags: magento, themes

I had implemented a custom theme in magento and after that its checkout/onepage is not working:

here it how it looks after custom theme implementation
[image: after custom theme added]

But it should look like:
[image]

It gives me the following errors on console:

1. TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function
   $('billing:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "");
2. TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
    $(this.form).observe('submit', function(event){this.save();Event.stop(event);}.b... //opcheckout.js
3. TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function
   $('shipping:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "");
4. TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
   $(this.form).observe('submit', function(event){this.save();Event.stop(event);}.b... // opcheckout.js
5. TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
    $(this.form).observe('submit', function(event){this.save();Event.stop(event);}.b... // opcheckout.js

Comment: there must a css/js conflict somewhere

Comment: where should I check that css/js conflict?

Comment: You're missing prototype.js. This is added to the head in layout/page.xml.